# Multiclass classification by One-Vs-Rest and Gradient Boosted Tree Classifier

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, multiclass-classification

I would like to build a `Gradient boosted tree` classifier by `PySpark`, for multiclass classification task. I have tried:

```
gb = GBTClassifier(maxIter=10)
ovr = OneVsRest(classifier=gb)
ovrModel = ovr.fit(trainingData)
gb_predictions = ovrModel.transform(valData)
evaluator = MulticlassClassificationEvaluator(metricName="accuracy")
gb_accuracy = evaluator.evaluate(gb_predictions)
```

When I run the code above, I get this error:

```
numClasses = int(dataset.agg({labelCol: "max"}).head()["max("+labelCol+")"]) + 1
AssertionError: Classifier <class 'pyspark.ml.classification.GBTClassifier'> doesn't extend from HasRawPredictionCol.
```

this is about the `ovrModel = ovr.fit(trainingData)` line, but I don't understand what is wrong with the training data.